# Get X random elements from table in database using Linq or lambda in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database with x amount users and I want to randomly get all the users and then write like 50 users out on my site.
Right now I'm only using `.take(50)` and retrieves the latest 50 users. I want it to shuffle 50 random from whole table, Any ideas?

This is what my code looks like now:

```
userList = userList.OrderBy(user => -user.ID).Take(userCount).ToList();
```

**NOTE:** `userlist` is my list of all users. and as you can see I'm at the moment using lambda with a variable called userCount where I say how many users to list out!

Comment: I want some kind of random use in this ofcourse. But I don't know how :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
userList = userList.OrderBy(user => rnd.Next()).Take(usercount).ToList();
```

Comment: Hehe thank you! It works :) Kinda easy lol, Should of figured it out by myself! :)

Comment: I will flag ur posts as "right" have to wait for 5 minutes tho :) @MikeSW

Comment: Does the `order by` clause assume that the number returned by the `rnd` object is a user id? What I mean is, is it possible to get an id which does not exist?

Comment: @AndreiV no it is not.

Comment: @Magnus I'm not quite getting it. What's the context of the random object? Does it apply to the ids or the indexes?

Comment: @AndreiV imagine `OrderBy(user => user.Id)` this orders the users by their Ids. `OrderBy(user => rnd.Next())` this "associates" a random number to every user and then orders by these numbers.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Thank you! That clears things up. The thing that confused me the most was the lack of an upper boundary in the `Next()` method. The inner workings are clear now.

Comment: How can you know rnd value will match with any account ID?

Comment: It isn't meant to match an id, it's meant to provide a number for ordering

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this depending on how many users are in your system

1.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>(50);
int total = userList.Count();
Random r = new Random();
while (ids.Count() < 50)
{
    var next = r.Next(total);
    if (!ids.Contains(next))
        ids.Add(next);
}
var users = userList.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.ID));
```

2.

MikeSW beat me to that one

Difference between the options is that 1) involves 2 queries queries to the database and 2) involves loading all of the users from the database just to load 50 of them. It's up to you which is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

When it is okay to load all users and then take 50 of them, you can use a while loop like this:

```
List<object> randomUsers = new List<User>();
Random r = new Random();
while (randomUsers.Count < 50)
{
    userList
      // skip previously selected users
      .Except(randomUsers)
      // random number to skip a random amount of users
      .Skip(r.Next(0, userList.Count() - 1 - randomUsers.Count))
      // and then take the next one
      .First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Id primary key column in your entity I would recommend to use the following query or you will be bringing down a lot of data for no reason.

```
var rnd = new Random();

// Get the employeeIds.
var employeeIds = EmployeeService.Data()
    .Select(e => e.Id)
    .ToList();

// Choose n number of random employeeIds.
var randomEmployeeIds = employeeIds
    .OrderBy(id => rnd.Next())
    .Take(x);

// Get random employees.
var employees = EmployeeService.Data().Where(emp => randomEmployeeIds.Contains(emp.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension Without Random

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetRandomItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Int32 count)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(count);
    }
}
```

And now you can

```
userList = userList.GetRandomItems().ToList();
```